# Can we have an electrolytic capacitor in the schematic editor?

Tags: support, circuitlab, schematic

At first: many thanks for [embedding CircuitLab](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2708/17592)! It's cool, easy to use, et cetera, et cetera. Major improvement of the site.

Here's a little feature request: *can we have an electrolytic capacitor as well?* Most of the time, I distinguish electrolytic and ceramic capacitors in my circuits - this increases readability. However, the CircuitLab tool doesn't have an electrolytic capacitor.

I hope this is on topic here, but perhaps I should ask CircuitLab directly? Their main editor doesn't have an electrolytic capacitor either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you place a cap, right click, "edit parameters" and choose polarized.  It's there already.

Comment: That's what they said too. :-)

Comment: You can also just double-click the capacitor (instead of using the right click menu) :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a feature request for circuitlab you need to contact circuitlab directly.

[Circuitlab feature request section of forum](https://www.circuitlab.com/forums/feature-requests/).

[Circuitlab support section of forum](https://www.circuitlab.com/forums/support/)

Comment: And if CircuitLab approves my request, will it be automatically added to this tool as well?

Comment: @CamilStaps Our tool is really just embedding using their tool. Any changes to their tool will apply to our tool. We are using a plugin of their tool, not a local copy.

Comment: Okay, thanks. For the sake of information: I posted a feature request at CircuitLab: https://www.circuitlab.com/forums/feature-requests/topic/wt6rukr3/electrolytic-capacitors/