# Circuitlab scematic editor: touch screen devices not supported message even though it used to work

Tags: support, feature-request, bug

I used to be able to use the circuitlab schematic editor until perhaps a month ago (I could be way off) on an Android tablet.

Why the regression? It used to work fine. I've noticed that going directly to the circuitlab website, the app loads with a warning but is unusable.

I hope this is known and being looked at? I'm sure the SE network have a lot of pull with circuitlab. I'm surprised they didn't object to letting this regression go through.

Circuitlab [say they support iOS touch devices](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/touch/) (only. Really?)

Comment: Related: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/whod-be-interested-in-having-systemvision-integrated-here

Comment: Its unlikely that you'll see any changes as Circuitlab is free for EE.SE and there is no incentive for Circuitlab to spend time to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Java on iOS (NOT)

But if you use Puffin Cloud browser on iOS, partially ok except you cannot draw wires as iOS thinks its a swipe.